# What's a google sheet formula for fractional part of the number

Tags: google-sheets

I need a formula to get only the fractional part of a given number. It should take any number and return its fractional part which is between 0 and 0.9999...
For example

```
123.456 -> 0.456
      0 -> 0
      1 -> 0
    0.1 -> 0.1
```

I tried google help, but did not find such a function.
I could use something like this, but I did not want to repeat the input expression: `X - FLOOR(X)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me, however it was [not documented](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497?hl=en) in the google help

```
=MOD(X;1)
```

Comment: This *sort of* works, but I've also come across floating point issues, for example `=mod(1000000000000.3,1)` produces `0.3000488281`, not `0.3` in Google Sheets. If you reduce a few of those zeroes to `=mod(10000000000.3,1)` the result is now `0.2999992371`. If you `FLOOR()` that result, as I was doing, you're going to get an incorrect result. It's bothersome.

Comment: As another example with less zeroes: `=floor(mod(100.3,1)*10)` gives you an incorrect answer `2`. I think the workaround for floating point errors like this is probably to `ROUND()` all numbers before using something like `FLOOR()`, `INT()` or `TRUNC()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
=X-INT(X)
```

where X is the cell reference to the cell you want the fraction of.

Comment: I know, but I did not want to repeat X, because X is a long expression

Comment: Auxillary column.   Calculate x in column C.  Column D is C-INT(C).  Hide C.  Or instead of C use column BX way out to the right.